# How to allow image or table using mPDF h2toc

Tags: pdf, yii2, mpdf

There's any way to allow `mpDF h2toc` to generate a list of table or image instead to `H1 - H6`?

Comment: http://www.mpdfonline.com/repos/mpdf42demo.pdf

Comment: try to upgrade newer version of [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)